# How to obtain the skeleton of a binary image with scikit-image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to draw the skeleton of the following image:

[image: original image]

I've tried with the following Python code:

```
import cv2
from skimage import morphology, color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.jpg')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image=color.rgb2gray(image)

skeleton =morphology.medial_axis(image)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))

ax1.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_title('original', fontsize=20)

ax2.imshow(skeleton, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.set_title('skeleton', fontsize=20)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And I got the following skeleton:

[image]

This doesn't look like the right skeleton image. I don't know what's going wrong.

Can anyone help me on this? Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 8):

Applying the medial axis as in your example:

```
from skimage import img_as_bool, io, color, morphology
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = img_as_bool(color.rgb2gray(io.imread('CIBUv.png')))
out = morphology.medial_axis(image)

f, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax1.imshow(out, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image: Medial Axis of binary image]

Note that, as @Aaron mentions below, converting to a boolean image first helps here, because your original image was stored in JPEG which could introduce small fluctuations in pixel values.

You can also replace `medial_axis` with `skeletonize` for a different algorithm.

If you want the outline as described in @Tonechas's answer, then look at edge detection methods.

Comment: I think the big thing that you did, but didn't emphasize is that converting to binary is going to clear up quite a bit.. I imagine slight differences in the white level of the original image was causing the skeleton artifacts.

Comment: note the original image was a jpeg, which would suffer these often imperceptible artifacts.

Comment: Silly me, I read the question in diagonal and didn't notice that the OP actually wanted the skeleton rather than the contour.

Comment: Thank you!! @Stefan, Aaron, Tonechas.


With the code here, I have successfully drawn the skeleton image.

You are really appreciated!!